# Question about Ubuntu default partitions

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

**Background:**

- I'm an Ubuntu noob, although I have used it before and installed it
  on an old laptop so I am aware of the convenient installation process
  and options.
- I'm planning to install Ubuntu 18.04 onto a blank 500GB SSD, and for
  now I don't plan to dual-boot (might do some hackintoshing at some
  point).
- I haven't done this before because in the past I have simply wiped
  the existing operating system and replaced with Ubuntu (because it
  was a useless Windows on an old machine).
- I have read a lot of stuff online about the benefits of manually
  partitioning the disk upon installation although I haven't done it
  myself before.
- Although a noob I'm prepared to go through the effort of doing
  partitions etc to generally learn more and improve my computer skills
  as well as optimising my system.

**Questions:**

- What does the Ubuntu 18.04 installer do in terms of default partitions if you choose to wipe the whole disk?
- I am wondering if it would be better to manually create /, home and swap instead?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 defaults to swapfile, so swap partition isn't needed. Having a /home is a personal choice (I prefer it), but if you stick with Ubuntu you don't gain all that much (but have to pick sizes, then deal with movements if you run out of space in one partition, have loads in other etc).  Ubuntu installer allows you to setup your own partitions anyway (using 'something else' option).  The best way is user-preference

Comment: @guiverc hits it better than me, I deleted my answer

Comment: Thanks both, @tannerli your answer was really helpful too!

Comment: Being a "Ubuntu noob", and having a "small-ish" SSD, I would recommend not manually partitioning at this point. Just install Ubuntu and take the standard defaults when "Use entire hard disk" selection. Learn manual partitioning later... you'll be glad you did :-)

Answer (score 0):

> What does the Ubuntu 18.04 installer do in terms of default partitions if you choose to wipe the whole disk?

1 partition for / and a boot partition.

> I am wondering if it would be better to manually create /, home and swap instead?

- don't forget to create a UEFI from BIOS. Is a one time task for a disk.
- we don't do swap on a partition anymore. The system will create and use a swapfile.
- I use the following setup after a few years of experimeniting:

  ```
  / 25 Gb (SSD).
  /home (Remainder of my SSD. When I had 1 disk I made /home/ 10Gb).
  /discworld (ie a "data partition"; My whole 1Tb HDD).
  ```

  Then I copy a backup of ~./config/users-dirs.dirs`over the default one. My version was edited to replace`$HOME/` with the mountpoint of the data partition.

  If you run services like apache or mysql edit those respective configuration files to point to a sub directory in the data partition.  Keep `/` and `/home` clean from user related files so you can instantly decide to do a reinstall. Makes also for an easy backup: backup your partition and you have it all saved.

Comment: Thank you. Why is it preferable to create a UEFI from BIOS?

Comment: Mandatory. not preferable. You need a hidden uefi partition to boot uefi and a new disk does not have one.

Comment: But any UEFI compatible OS will create the ESP if installed in a blank drive.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, basically when I install Ubuntu on the blank disk everything will be done for me by default, and if I want to partition manually, I need to remember to make the ESP. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, you're right. There's only one potential problem you may experience: If the drive was used before in a BIOS/Legacy installation, even if all partitions have been removed the old partition table (MBR) remains and you'll have to use a tool like GParted in the live session to make a new partition table as GPT before starting the installation. Then the installer will take care of everything, including the creation of the ESP.